# HTML text box or area with scrollbars, to be filled with Ajax response

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, textarea

I need to create a fixed size (`height and width`) text area or box in a HTML page. This area will be filled with responses from Ajax requests. Some of these responses will be too big to fit within this area, therefore, some scroll bars should be displayed. Nice to have (but not must have), users should be to select the content of the box.

How to achieve this best in HTML? It seems like `textarea` could be a solution, but how do I work with `height and width` rather `col and rows`? If possible, I would like to avoid having to use a form just for this `textarea`. Should I use a separate Javascript/Jquery library instead?

I am looking for code examples to design/implement this box. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
<textarea class="myTextarea"></textarea>
```

and add some CSS style

```
.myTextarea {
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
}
```

do you already have the code to populate the text area with the Ajax response?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I had tried this, but it did not work. But that was because I was deleting the textarea before using it. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS :

```
.className {
 width: 500px;
 height: 400px;
 overflow: scroll; /*This is not required, if it's a text area*/
}
```

The HTML :

```
<div class="className"> </div>
```

OR

```
<textarea class=".className"> </textarea>
```

The JQuery:

```
var ajax_control = jQuery.ajax({
    url: "target.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {variable_name: variable_value}
});
ajax_control.always(function(){
    $('.className').append(ajax_control.responseText);
        //$('.className').html(ajax_control.responseText);
        //$('.className').val(ajax_control.responseText); // if this is a textarea
});
```